# How come my only 1 of my raphael.JS circles are animating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, raphael

In my HTML documents, I have 2 divs:

```
  <div id="raphael"></div>
  <div id="raphael1"></div>
```

I am using raphael to animate 2 circles but only 1 is animating properly. The other animates from leftCircle to rightCircle but stops.

Why is the second circle (raphael1) not animating properly?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    circleRight = function() {
        newCircle = {
            'transform' : 't100,0'
        }
        circ.animate(newCircle, 1000, 'linear', circleLeft)
    }
    circleLeft = function() {
        newCircle = {
            'transform' : 't0,0'
        }
        circ.animate(newCircle, 1000, 'linear', circleRight)
    }
    setup = function() {
        paper = Raphael('raphael', 320, 320)
        circ = paper.circle(100, 50, 30)
        circleRight()
    }
    //circle 2

    circleRight1 = function() {
        newCircle1 = {
            'transform' : 't100,0'
        }
        circ.animate(newCircle1, 1000, 'linear', circleLeft1)
    }
    circleLeft1 = function() {
        newCircle1 = {
            'transform' : 't0,0'
        }
        circ.animate(newCircle1, 1000, 'linear', circleRight1)
    }
    setup1 = function() {
        paper = Raphael('raphael1', 320, 320)
        circ = paper.circle(100, 50, 30)
        circleRight1()
    }

    $(document).ready(setup)
    $(document).ready(setup1)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There are too many misusage of JavaScript in your code. Most prompt one that's giving you error is that you're not respecting the variable scope.

> In JS variables have functional scope if declared using var, otherwise they have global (whatever global object is) scope.

Here's the fixed code. [Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6f3557t/1/)

```
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function () {
    var circleRight = function (circ) {
        var newCircle = {
            'transform': 't100,0'
        };
        circ.animate(newCircle, 1000, 'linear', function () {
            circleLeft(circ);
        });
    };
    var circleLeft = function (circ) {
        var newCircle = {
            'transform': 't0,0'
        };
        circ.animate(newCircle, 1000, 'linear', function () {
            circleRight(circ);
        });
    };
    var setup = function () {
        var paper = new Raphael('raphael', 320, 320);
        var circ = paper.circle(100, 50, 30);
        circleRight(circ);
    };
    //circle 2

    var circleRight1 = function (circ) {
        var newCircle1 = {
            'transform': 't100,0'
        };
        circ.animate(newCircle1, 1000, 'linear', function () {
            circleLeft1(circ);
        });
    };
    var circleLeft1 = function (circ) {
        var newCircle1 = {
            'transform': 't0,0'
        };
        circ.animate(newCircle1, 1000, 'linear', function () {
            circleRight1(circ);
        });
    };
    var setup1 = function () {
        var paper = new Raphael('raphael1', 320, 320);
        var circ = paper.circle(100, 50, 30);
        circleRight1(circ);
    };

    setup();
    setup1();
});
```

Here are some links for understanding JavaScript better.

- [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook)
- [Douglas Crockford lectures on JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2ifWcnQs6M&list=PL62E185BB8577B63D)
- [Crockford on JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxAXlJEmNMg&list=PL7664379246A246CB) (Since big bang)
- http://www.jslint.com/ (Not for the faint of heart)